# How can I serialize an int value with json without class object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, primitive-types

I want to serialize an integer into a file as a json object. Normally, I can serialize **with object** (other class object) like this;

```
void Serialize()
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented );
            File.WriteAllText(path_combined, json);

        }
```

`obj` is the communication bridge with other class, however **I have integers in this class**, so I have to serialize without object. I looked other questions, they all use objects. I couldn't find a way to **convert an integer to json string(or whatever it is) to serialize.** Can you please help?

Comment: What is the output you expect to see? JSON - being "JavaScript **Object** Notation" - cannot have 'naked' integers, it has to be a field of an object

Comment: What is "this class", and what is the output that you want to get when you serialize it?  Are you trying to serialize an array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. "I have integers in this class", well, so? What difference does this make? Basically your question is stating that you're unable to serialize an object containing integers, but no other information. Serializing an object with integers is fine, supported, 100% OK, *normally*, but if you have a specific case where you don't want/can't do this, please elaborate more about this situation because otherwise we're just guessing at what the real issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any type, including Integer **is** object in C#. So basically you can serialize integer like you mentioned, e.g.:

```
int myInt = 10;
string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myInt); 
// 10
string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { myInt }); // new object with int field
//{"myInt":10}
```

JSON string itself is bunch of key-value pairs (string keys and string / int / array of strings or ints / object values) wrapped into object, but single int it convets to single int string.

So you can not serialize int like { 10 } because this is not valid JSON.

More here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: You can pass `myInt` to be serialized, but the output is not what you've indicated. The serialization method wouldn't be able to know the name of the variable you used. It wouldn't even know if you passed in the literal `10` or the variable `myInt`.